# Keras IMDB Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, keras

I am new to ML, and I am trying to use Keras for sentiment analysis on the IMDB dataset, based on a tutorial I found. The code below runs and gives an accuracy of around 90% on the test data. However, when I try to predict two easy sentences (one positive, one negative), it gives a value of around 0.50 for the positive and 0.73 for the negative, where it should give 0.71 for the positive and less than 0.1 for the negative, which are the results shown in the tutorial.

Any ideas what the problem is?

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
import numpy as np

top_words = 5000  # 5000
# first tuple is data and sentiment lists,
# the second is testing data with sentiment
# https://keras.io/datasets/
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

# reverse lookup
word_to_id = imdb.get_word_index()
'''word_to_id = {k: (v + INDEX_FROM) for k, v in word_to_id.items()}'''
word_to_id["<PAD>"] = 0
word_to_id["<START>"] = 1
word_to_id["<UNK>"] = 2

# Truncate and pad the review sequences, to take only the first 500 words
max_review_length = 500
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=max_review_length)

# Build the model

# embedding translates the words in a n dimensional
# space so "hi" becomes (0.2,0.1,0.5) in a 3 dimensional space
# it is the first layer of the network
embedding_vector_length = 32  # dimensions

# https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/
model = Sequential()  # sequential is a linear stack of layers

# layer of 500 x 32
model.add(
    Embedding(
        top_words,  # how many words to consider based on count
        embedding_vector_length,  # dimensions
        input_length=max_review_length))  # input vector
model.add(LSTM(100))  # the parameter are the memory units of the LSTM
# If you want you can replace LSTM by a flatten layer
# model.add(LSTM(100))
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # output 0<y<1 for every x
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


# Train the model
model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    epochs=1)  # original epochs = 3, batch-size = 64

# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))

# predict sentiment from reviews
bad = "this movie was terrible and bad"
good = "i really liked the movie and had fun"
for review in [good, bad]:
    tmp = []
    for word in review.split(" "):
        tmp.append(word_to_id[word])
    tmp_padded = sequence.pad_sequences([tmp], maxlen=max_review_length)
    print("%s. Sentiment: %s" % (
        review, model.predict(np.array([tmp_padded[0]]))))
# i really liked the movie and had fun. Sentiment: 0.715537
# this movie was terrible and bad. Sentiment: 0.0353295
```

Answer (score 1):

"Any ideas what the problem is?" There may not be a problem, per se. I have a few thoughts, in order of likely influence:

1. If your two sentences are not representative of an IMDB review, then one can expect the model to predict poorly and erratically.
2. Your model only has a single epoch, and the model may not have had enough opportunity to learn a robust mapping from review to sentiment (assuming such a mapping is possible given the data).
3. There is a random element to neural networks, and as a result, the model you have developed will probably not predict identically to the model in the tutorial.
4. With "an accuracy of around 90%", one would expect (depending on the class distribution) around 1 in 10 predictions to be incorrect. A small number of instances (two, in your case) are generally not a good way to evaluate the performance of a model.

When I ran your code, I got a training accuracy of around 80% and test accuracy of around 85%, and "i really liked the movie and had fun. Sentiment: [[0.75149596]]" and "this movie was terrible and bad. Sentiment: [[0.93544275]]".

Comment: The arguments that you have stated sound reasonable. However, do you think they can contribute to such a big discrepancy between the tutorial and what I get? 0.75 for the positive and 0.93 for the negative, which you also get is completely wrong in terms of the actual sentiment, which should approach 0 for the negative and 1 for the positive.
P.S. I have tried with more epochs, which increase the accuracy, but the prediction for the two sentences is still wrong.

Comment: I think so. In my experience, NLP models can be sensitive to how closely test sentences match the training data. I assume that the code is correct because it is coming from a tutorial and runs for me also. Maybe toss some sentences similar to your two test sentences into your training data? See what happens?

Comment: Maybe try expanding the number of top words?

Comment: I haven't had much time lately to work on this, but I will try your suggestions and let you know what happens. Thank you.